# Ubuntu 20.04 does not detect external monitor through HDMI/DisplayPort adapter

Tags: 20.04, multiple-monitors, hdmi, displayport

I am trying to set up an external monitor to my laptop (Lenovo ThinkPad E14 Gen2). The monitor doesn't have an HDMI port, so I am using an HDMI/Display port adapter, but Ubuntu doesn't seem to detect the monitor. When I use the HDMI cable without the adapter (i.e. with my TV) it works perfectly.

This is the output of xrandr:

```
Screen 0: minimum 320 x 200, current 1920 x 1080, maximum 16384 x 16384
eDP-1 connected primary 1920x1080+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 309mm x 174mm
   1920x1080     60.02*+  60.01    59.97    59.96    59.93  
   1680x1050     59.95    59.88  
   1600x1024     60.17  
   1400x1050     59.98  
   1600x900      59.99    59.94    59.95    59.82  
   1280x1024     60.02  
   1440x900      59.89  
   1400x900      59.96    59.88  
   1280x960      60.00  
   1440x810      60.00    59.97  
   1368x768      59.88    59.85  
   1360x768      59.80    59.96  
   1280x800      59.99    59.97    59.81    59.91  
   1152x864      60.00  
   1280x720      60.00    59.99    59.86    59.74  
   1024x768      60.04    60.00  
   960x720       60.00  
   928x696       60.05  
   896x672       60.01  
   1024x576      59.95    59.96    59.90    59.82  
   960x600       59.93    60.00  
   960x540       59.96    59.99    59.63    59.82  
   800x600       60.00    60.32    56.25  
   840x525       60.01    59.88  
   864x486       59.92    59.57  
   800x512       60.17  
   700x525       59.98  
   800x450       59.95    59.82  
   640x512       60.02  
   720x450       59.89  
   700x450       59.96    59.88  
   640x480       60.00    59.94  
   720x405       59.51    58.99  
   684x384       59.88    59.85  
   680x384       59.80    59.96  
   640x400       59.88    59.98  
   576x432       60.06  
   640x360       59.86    59.83    59.84    59.32  
   512x384       60.00  
   512x288       60.00    59.92  
   480x270       59.63    59.82  
   400x300       60.32    56.34  
   432x243       59.92    59.57  
   320x240       60.05  
   360x202       59.51    59.13  
   320x180       59.84    59.32  
HDMI-1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
DP-1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
DP-2 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
DP-3 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
DP-4 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
```

This is the output of `lspci -k | grep -EA3 'VGA|3D|Display'`:

````
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation Device 9a49 (rev 01)
        Subsystem: Lenovo Device 5088
        Kernel driver in use: i915
        Kernel modules: i915

And this is the output of ```lshw -C video```:
  *-display                 
       description: VGA compatible controller
       product: Intel Corporation
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 2
       bus info: pci@0000:00:02.0
       logical name: /dev/fb0
       version: 01
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pciexpress msi pm vga_controller bus_master cap_list rom fb
       configuration: depth=32 driver=i915 latency=0 mode=1920x1080 visual=truecolor xres=1920 yres=1080
       resources: iomemory:600-5ff iomemory:400-3ff irq:167 memory:601c000000-601cffffff memory:4000000000-400fffffff ioport:4000(size=64) memory:c0000-dffff memory:4010000000-4016ffffff memory:4020000000-40ffffffff
````

I've seen in a lot of posts that the problem lies in the NVIDIA drivers, but I seem to have none installed. My kernel version is 5.11.0-37-generic.

Thanks in advance!

**Edit:**

I've tried this with another laptop and it doesn't work either, so maybe it's the adapter.

Comment: If the TV works I do not think driver. It may just be the monitor will not work with that adapter. Some signal it needs is not getting through. I have had that problem myself with adapters.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Does it mean I have to try out with another adapter? Or does it mean it will not work at all?

Comment: It could be a bad adapter or no adapter of that type will work I would have no way of knowing.

Comment: Thanks! I already tried with another laptop and it doesn't work either so maybe it's the adapter.

Comment: Are you aware that HDMI/Displayport adaptors/cables are directional (well, all the ones I know about anyway). They only work when plugged in the right way around. So you can buy either a HDMI to DP OR a DP to HDMI adaptor. You need of course HDMI to DP (HDMI source outputting to a DP monitor).

Comment: This ^^^ or the adapter is defective.